# Balls in minimal systems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

If $(X,T)$ is a minimal system uniquely ergodic with $\mu$, is there $p\in X$ such that $\mu(\partial B(p,t))=0$ for all $t>0$?

Comment: For $X=\{a,b\}$, $\partial B(p,t)$ is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ be an irrational rotation of the circle. We modify the metric on the circle as follows, letting $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ be the standard metric on the circle; and for $C$ a non-empty closed subset of the reals, let $D(x,C)$ denote the distance from $x$ to $C$. Let $C$ be a Cantor set of positive measure contained in $[\frac 14,\frac 12]$ and containing $\frac 14$ and
define a new metric by
$$
\rho(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
d(x,y)&\text{if $d(x,y)<\frac 14$}\\
\tfrac 14+D(d(x,y),C)&\text{if $d(x,y)\ge \frac 14$.}
\end{cases}
$$
This generates the same topology as the original metric.
But $\partial B(p,\frac 14)=p\pm C$.

Comment: I believe you have changed the question in response to my answer to your question. Please don't do this! Instead, leave the original question (you can correct any errors if there are any), but add a section labeled "ADDITIONAL QUESTION IN RESPONSE TO ANSWER"; or ask a completely new question referencing this question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @ManuelSaavedra's modified follow-up question:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368608/balls-in-minimal-systems-ii .